# Computing averages of chunks of a column

Tags: awk

I have a tab delim file

```
LOC105758527    1       55001   0.469590
LOC105758527    1       65001   0.067909
LOC105758527    1       75001   0.220712
LOC100218126    1       85001   0.174872
LOC105758529    1       125001  0.023420
NRF1    1       155001  0.242222
NRF1    1       165001  0.202569
NRF1    1       175001  0.327963
UBE2H   1       215001  0.063989
UBE2H   1       225001  0.542340
KLHDC10 1       255001  0.293471
KLHDC10 1       265001  0.231621
KLHDC10 1       275001  0.142917
TMEM209 1       295001  0.273941
CPA2    1       315001  0.181312
```

I need to calculate the average for col 4 for each element in col 1. So the sum/line count and print col1,2,3 of the 1st line in the computation and the avg as col 4.

I started with just doing the sum

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
        { y[$1] += $4; $4 = y[$1]; x[$1] = $0; }
END { for (i in x) { print x[i]; } }' file
```

But I'm getting

```
NRF1    1       175001  0.772754
LOC105758529    1       125001  0.02342
LOC100218126    1       85001   0.174872
KLHDC10 1       275001  0.668009
CPA2    1       315001  0.181312
TMEM209 1       295001  0.273941
UBE2H   1       225001  0.606329
LOC105758527    1       75001   0.758211
```

Which means it's jumping to some line other than the 1st in my file (and printing col1,2,3 from the last line calculated - which is fine but I would prefer the 1st line instead). The output is out of order.

I also don't know how to divide the sum by their NRs to actually get the average

Comment: Why are `LOC100218126`, `LOC105758529` not in the output?

Comment: "Which means it's jumping to some line" -- I don't see how you're coming to that conclusion. Note that awk arrays are associative arrays which have *no inherent order*. When you do `for (i in x) ...`, you get the array keys in what looks like random order. If you need the order, you need to keep an indexed array of the keys.

Comment: The sample data in your question has very little value, since you're showing lines in your output that don't appear in the sample input. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: By jumping I mean it's not reading from the first line but instead randomly. The file is huge, so I'dind't post where those lines came from, and I don't think they are needed to understand the question. Example fixed for LOC100218126, LOC105758529.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in just awk by using arrays to store line ordering and intermediate computation steps:

```
# set fields delimiters
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }

# print the header
NR==1 { print; next }

# the first time col1 value occurs, store col1..col3
!h[$1] {
    h[$1] = ++n  # save ordering
    d[n] = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3  # save first 3 columns
}

# store sum and quantity of col4
{
    i = h[$1]  # recover ordering
    s[i] += $4
    q[i]++
}

# output col1..col3 and the average value
END {
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print d[i], s[i]/q[i]
}
```

---

I see you have edited the question since I wrote the above. If your data has no header then the `NR==1` line will not be required.

If your data file is **really** big, the script above may consume too much memory (it will use memory proportional to the number of unique values for col1). If this will be problematic and the order of the output lines is not important, memory usage can be reduced drastically by pre-sorting the data (perhaps with `sort -k1,1 -s`), and producing output incrementally:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }

$1 != c1 {
    if (c1) print d, s/q
    d = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3
    s = q = 0
    c1 = $1
}

{
    s += $4
    q++
}

END { print d, s/q }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` script attempt. Not sure I fully understand the task with so many changes.

`script.awk`

```
BEGIN {OFS="\t"}  # assign output field separtor to tab
$1 == currFields[1]{  # handle a repeated line
    lineCount++;      # increment line counter
    currFields[4] += $4; # accumulate the sum of 4th field
    next;             # skip any output and read next line.
}
{                     # handle a new line not seen before
    outputPrevLine(); # print out the prvious line
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) currFields[i] = $i; # store current line values
    lineCount = 0;    # reset line counter
}
END {outputPrevLine();} # output the last line even if repeated.
function outputPrevLine() { 
    if (NR == 1) return; # discard first line, since it contains no value.
    print currFields[1], currFields[2], currFields[3], currFields[4]/(lineCount + 1);
}
```

`input.txt`

```
LOC105758527    1       55001   0.469590
LOC105758527    1       65001   0.067909
LOC105758527    1       75001   0.220712
LOC100218126    1       85001   0.174872
LOC105758529    1       125001  0.023420
NRF1    1       155001  0.242222
NRF1    1       165001  0.202569
NRF1    1       175001  0.327963
UBE2H   1       215001  0.063989
UBE2H   1       225001  0.542340
KLHDC10 1       255001  0.293471
KLHDC10 1       265001  0.231621
KLHDC10 1       275001  0.142917
TMEM209 1       295001  0.273941
CPA2    1       315001  0.181312
```

running:

```
 sort input.txt | awk -f script.awk
```

output:

```
CPA2    1       315001  0.181312
KLHDC10 1       255001  0.22267
LOC100218126    1       85001   0.174872
LOC105758527    1       55001   0.252737
LOC105758529    1       125001  0.02342
NRF1    1       155001  0.257585
TMEM209 1       295001  0.273941
UBE2H   1       215001  0.303165
```

Comment: I had done it. Doesn't show up for you? It shows up here.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldnt figure how to index an array and how to divide the sum by the counts at once
My solution to this was to sort the output of

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
        { y[$1] += $4; $4 = y[$1]; x[$1] = $0; }
END { for (i in x) { print x[i]; } }' file | sort -V -k2,3 > temp1
```

and save it to a temp1 file.

Then count the uniq occurrences in col1 in my original file together with some text reformatting by doing

```
cut -f1 test | uniq -c | sed 's/^\s\+//g ; s/\s/\t/' > temp2
```

and saving to a temp2 file

then I just pasted temp1 and temp2 and divided the sum column by the count column by doing

```
paste temp1 temp2 | awk -F$'\t' '{$6 = $4 / $5}1' > output
```

Where last 4th col is the sum, 5th col is the count and 6th col is the average

```
LOC105758527  1  75001   0.758211  3  0.252737
LOC100218126  1  85001   0.174872  1  0.174872
LOC105758529  1  125001  0.02342   1  0.02342
NRF1          1  175001  0.772754  3  0.257585
UBE2H         1  225001  0.606329  2  0.303165
KLHDC10       1  275001  0.668009  3  0.22267
TMEM209       1  295001  0.273941  1  0.273941
CPA2          1  315001  0.181312  1  0.181312
```

Then rm temp files